# How to send javascript arrays to a servlet using JSONObject

Tags: javascript, json, servlets

I have 2 arrays for storing latitude and longitude of some locations in javascript. I want to send these two arrays to a java servlet. I am sending the JSON String like this:
                
    function saveGeoPts()
    {

```
var GeoPts = [
 { "lati" : "18.55" , "longi" : "73.88" }, 
 { "lati" : "18.67" , "longi" : "73.89" }, 
 { "lati" : "18.59" , "longi" : "73.99" }, ];

for(var i=0;i<GeoPts.length;i++)
{
    //document.write(GeoPts[i].lati+"  "+GeoPts[i].longi+"   ");
}
// convert JSON to string
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(GeoPts);
document.getElementById('jsonData').value = jsonString;

}</script>
</head>
 <body>
<form action="Controller" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="jsonData" name="jsonData" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="saveGeoPts()" >
</form>
</body>
```

And trying to fetch this way

```
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws      ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.print("in post");
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String jsonString = request.getParameter("jsonData");
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
        System.out.print(jsonObject.get("lati"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is working or not working?

Comment: not working. and I am not understanding whether it is the right way or not

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Try printing jsonString on the server side. What do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question i see how you prepare your data

```
var data = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```

I don't see how you send. I recommended you to use jQuery ajax to do that things.

```
var GeoPts = [
 { "lati" : "18.55" , "longi" : "73.88" }, 
 { "lati" : "18.67" , "longi" : "73.89" }, 
 { "lati" : "18.59" , "longi" : "73.99" } 
];

$.ajax({
  url: "YOUR_URL",
  data: GeoPts,
  type: "POST"

}).done(function(response) {

  // your logic of success callback

}).error(function(error){

  // your logic of error callback

});
```

If you want send to your server data in this format: "param=1&paramt=3....".
You can use this:

```
$.param({param:1 , paramT:3});
// output "param=1&paramT=3"
```

Comment: I am setting this JSON object in an hidden parameter and sending to servlet using form